# swiftUI -I want to move the position of the item in the tabbar

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

I want to align the top position of the items in the red box of picture 2 as shown in picture 1.

When an item is selected, the image is automatically aligned. Is there a way to float the padding from the tab bar based on the top of the image?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, You should always post the code which you tried so that people answering can get idea of what efforts are done from your end and what can be improved/helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can move the position of Image by using this code. If you used title with that image so you should use this title in place of nil.

```
 extension UITabBarController {    
    override open func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let items = tabBar.items
        for item in items!
        {
            if item.title == nil {
                item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some description for your answer.

Comment: When I apply the following padding,  `UIEdgeInsets(top: -50, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)`, the image moves out of the tab bar (as expected) and can no longer handle tap gestures. Do you know of a workaround for this? I still want the image to be tappable if it is outside of the tab bar.